# Is approx() designed to be used with complex numbers?

Tags: r, complex-numbers

I did the following experiment, since there's no mention of complex data on the `approx` help page:

```
Rgames> zfoo
[1] 1+ 6i 2+ 7i 3+ 8i 4+ 9i 5+10i
Rgames> approx(zfoo,n=10)
$x
 [1] 1.000000 1.444444 1.888889 2.333333 2.777778 3.222222 3.666667 4.111111
 [9] 4.555556 5.000000

$y
 [1]  6.000000  6.444444  6.888889  7.333333  7.777778  8.222222  8.666667
 [8]  9.111111  9.555556 10.000000
```

Digging into the code for `approx`, I discovered that `xy.coords` (also apparently undocumented for complex data) treats the Real and Imag parts of complex data as the `x` and `y` parts of coordinate data.  So my question is: is this intended behavior?  I'm always a bit paranoid about depending on functionality that isn't explicitly documented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks intentional and reliable to me, as `approx()` calls `regularize.values()`, which calls `xy.coords()`, which includes this code block:

```
else if (is.complex(x)) {
    y <- Im(x)
    x <- Re(x)
    xlab <- paste0("Re(", ylab, ")")
    ylab <- paste0("Im(", ylab, ")")
}
```

following which `approx()` carries on just as it would had you passed it numeric (real/rational) vectors `x` and `y`.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- FWIW, based on the comment introducing `regularize.values` in the R sources, I now lean towards the authors *not* having contemplated its application to complex numbers. Sort of immaterial, though, as long as the function performs reliably and your application of it makes sense!